# USB to male bullet connector

Tags: power, usb, analog, charger

I'm looking for simplest possible solution to power a load via USB to male bullet connector.

Requirements:

- +5V input voltage
- 15V output voltage
- 1,5A output current on the bullet connector
- very low cost
- low part count
- simple and accessible parts (no specialized ICs)

Low noise and ripple would be nice, but isn't obligatory.

The piece is to charge a portable music box via USB.
I have sufficient skills for the assembly but don't quite trust my second-semester EE knowledge. This is my first analog project.
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You need to: 1. Realise this is not a design committee, but a Q&A site. We're not here to design your stuff for you. Which leads to 2. Show your own research efforts in your question and be specific what you need help with (and it can't be "everything"). 3. Realise that 1.5A * 15V = 22.5W = over 4 times what a high-power USB port can handle. Foolishly assuming 100% conversion efficiency. As it stands this post is asking for closure.

Comment: @Asmyldof 1. sorry, I was not intending to offend you or anyone else. I am very unexperienced and my first thought was to ask people who understand what they are doing.
2. I am looking for the answer if it can be done, not directly requesting a full blueprint.
3. is there a way around it?

Comment: @BlkPengu only way around it is by increasing the power at the supply, or decreasing your load. Smaller speakers? Charge a battery at a slower rate? Lower the voltage you need? Figure that any power converter will only be 85~90% efficient, so your input will need to beat your output power needs. A 12V 2A power supply will be much better/smaller than a 5V 5A supply. USB is typically not seen at these high currents. Ideally, you can just start with a 15V 2A supply (never use a supply at 100% of its rated output, for safety)

Comment: @Passerby I was looking for a solution for already bought speakers and an already bought USB source (not mine, friend who didn't check the requirements, the fool). Since there is no cable for that kind of charging I was looking to make the converter for him, but i guess now I know why there is no such converter around. thx for the input!

Comment: If you think this is answered, by Bitsmacks answer, then click the accept below the arrows on his answer.

Comment: @Passerby will this call a closing vote? This is literally my second post and my first post in EEC

Comment: @BlkPengu it marks it as having an accepted answer which is good. Closed is different, and basically bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USB ports are not designed to provide that much power.

\$P = V \cdot I \quad \Rightarrow \quad I=\frac PV\$

To calculate your desired output power:

\$P = 15V \cdot 1.5A = 22.5W\$

Now, to relate this to the input:

\$I = \frac PV = \frac {22.5W}{5V} = 4.5A\$

So, you would need to draw 4.5 A from the USB port.

USB 2.0 limits the port output to 500mA (0.5A). There are other USB options: A high-capacity charger might provide you 2.2A.  There's a newer "power delivery" spec which allows for 3A.  Unfortunately, all of these are insufficient for your application.

Comment: Even a high capacity tablet usb charger (not a pc port) is still only 11 Watts/2.2 Amps. USB 3/C Power Delivery allows for 3 Amps at 5V, but thats still only 15 Watts.

Comment: sounds like this project is closed. thanks for the answers everyone :) I learned a great deal here